# Displaying child records in data grid in WPF using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have two tables named **Process** and **ProcessTriggers**. ProcessTriggers referring Process table.And need to create a screen to diplay Process as well as the ProcessTrigger related to the Process. I have created data objects using entity framework and my classes look like.

```
public partial class Process
    {  
       public Process()
        {
            this.ProcessTriggers = new ObservableCollection<ProcessTrigger>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int WorkflowID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsBatch { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedOn { get; set; }

        public virtual ObservableCollection<ProcessTrigger> ProcessTriggers { get; set; }
}
```

And my view model look like..

```
public class ProcessViewModel : ViewModel<Process>
{
    private RelayCommand saveCommand;
    private RelayCommand cancelCommand;

    public ProcessViewModel()
    {
        using(var context = new PACEContext())
        {
            this.Entity = context.Processes.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == 1);
            IsInEditMode = true;
        }
    }
 }
```

I am binding these viewModel to my View, Entity properties are bound correctly, but the **ProcessTriggerCollection is not binding to datagrid**..

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entity.ProcessTriggers}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
                    </DataGrid>
```

I juts started learning WPF, MVVM and Entity framework.Can any one help.?

Comment: Did you bind the DataContext of your view to an instance of your ViewModel?

Comment: Is LazyLoading enabled? If not then you have to eager load the Navigation Property. Did you validate that Entity.ProcessTriggers isn't null?

Comment: do you see any binding error messages in the debugger output window?

Comment: Hi, If I debug and see the records in the collection then the grid loaded with records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the Process have a ObservableCollection of other class called ProcessTriggers.

Why you don't create a ObservableCollection and binding this?

```
private ObservableCollection<ProcessTrigger> _listProcessTriggers;
    public ObservableCollection<ProcessTrigger> ListProcessTriggers
    {
        get { return _listProcessTriggers; }
        set { _listProcessTriggers= value; RaisePropertyChanged("ListProcessTriggers"); }
    }

public ProcessViewModel()
{
    using(var context = new PACEContext())
    {
        this.Entity = context.Processes.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == 1);
        ListProcessTriggers = Entity.ProcessTriggers;
        IsInEditMode = true;
    }
}
```

And In Xmal Binding

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListProcessTriggers}" AutoGenerateColumns="True />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but this is the solution I already done to fix this problem.. :)